# Angular Injectror

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have a few components; I'm using Injector in constructor for encapsulation

```
import { Component, Injector, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base',
  templateUrl: './base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base.component.css'],
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  some = '';

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    this.some = injector.get(this.some);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

I'm using BaseComponent in other Component

```
import { BaseComponent } from '../base/base.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base-state',
  templateUrl: './base-state.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base-state.component.css'],
})
export class BaseStateComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    super(injector);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

BaseStateComponent I'm going to use in others component; Question is:
Is there any way, to make injector in BaseComponent or BaseSateComponent Optional;
I have a case, when I need a component, but I don't need an injector of it;

I know about feature

```
constructor(@Optional(), @Self() etc...);
```

But truly to say, I can't understand how it work's; I will be grateful if somebody can explain it Decorators;

[stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkcfnm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbase-state.component.ts)

Comment: Use `@Optional()`,  `constructor(@Optional() injector: Injector)`?, the optional decorator marks the injector parameter in the constructor as an optional dependency, which is exactly what you want right?

Comment: Yeas, but no; I try to do this, but I get same result, in component constructor awaiting 1 argument "injectro"

Comment: I'm quoting to you what the angular documentation says and I've used it myself on several occasions to mark parameters as optional, maybe post the error?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkcfnm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbase-state.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want to use **@Optional @Self** to make **injector optional**. But, **@optional @self** works well with something that is **injectable** which you can provide in **providers** array at some level. In Angular, services are **injectable**. So you can use **@Optional @Self @SkipSelf** with services or something injectable

When you use **constrocutor(private someService:SomeService)**, Angular will check whether **SomeService** is provided at **componoent level** means in **@component**'s **providers**, if not, is it provided at **Module Level**, if not , is it provided at **Root level**? This way angular checks entire **Injector tree**.

When you use **@Optional**, it will not perform this check and so on....

***Keep in mind that Injector resolves a token into a dependency***.

## Answer to your question

You can use **optional parameter** approach in typescript by simply providing  **?** mark next to parameter as shown below,

```
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  some = '';

  constructor(private injector?: Injector) {             // ? to make parameter optional
    this.some = injector.get(this.some);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

*it also makes sense because you are using OOPs over classes.*

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wn86ud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbase.component.ts)** (Fixed some other issues also)